# Can't use properly Elasticsearch source connector in kafka, what's a matter?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I try to learn kafka-connect in apache kafka.
But I have some error, so what should I do? what's the matter?

- I create directory confluent-hub to store connector

> plugin.path=connectors/confluent-hub-components

Anyone know about the difference between:

```
connect-file-source.properties and  connect-console-sink.properties
```

So when i run in standalone:

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties
```

they give this error:

```
    [2022-09-19 22:34:49,152] INFO Kafka Connect standalone worker initializing ... (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:68)
[2022-09-19 22:34:49,158] INFO WorkerInfo values: 
    jvm.args = -Xms256M, -Xmx2G, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35, -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent, -XX:MaxInlineLevel=15, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false, -Dkafka.logs.dir=/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../logs, -Dlog4j.configuration=file:bin/../config/connect-log4j.properties
    jvm.spec = Ubuntu, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 11.0.16, 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04
    jvm.classpath = /home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/connect-api-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/connect-json-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-client-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.6.1.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.6.1.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.6.1.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.13.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.13.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.13.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.13.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.13.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.13.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jackson-module-scala_2.13-2.13.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jakarta.inject-2.6.1.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/javassist-3.27.0-GA.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.34.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.34.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.34.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.34.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jersey-hk2-2.34.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.34.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jetty-client-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jetty-util-ajax-9.4.48.v20220622.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jline-3.21.0.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/jose4j-0.7.9.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/kafka_2.13-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/kafka-metadata-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/kafka-raft-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/kafka-server-common-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/kafka-shell-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/kafka-storage-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/kafka-storage-api-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-scala_2.13-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-test-utils-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/maven-artifact-3.8.4.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/metrics-core-4.1.12.1.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/netty-buffer-4.1.78.Final.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/netty-codec-4.1.78.Final.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/netty-common-4.1.78.Final.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/netty-handler-4.1.78.Final.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/netty-resolver-4.1.78.Final.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/netty-transport-4.1.78.Final.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.78.Final.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.78.Final.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.78.Final.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/paranamer-2.8.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/plexus-utils-3.3.0.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.12.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/reload4j-1.2.19.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-6.29.4.1.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/scala-collection-compat_2.13-2.6.0.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/scala-java8-compat_2.13-1.0.2.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.13.8.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/scala-logging_2.13-3.9.4.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/scala-reflect-2.13.8.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.8.4.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/trogdor-3.2.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/zookeeper-jute-3.6.3.jar:/home/sarindra/Téléchargements/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/kafka_2.13-3.2.3/bin/../libs/zstd-jni-1.5.2-1.jar
    os.spec = Linux, amd64, 5.15.0-47-generic
    os.vcpus = 8
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerInfo:71)
[2022-09-19 22:34:49,159] INFO Scanning for plugin classes. This might take a moment ... (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:77)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,152] INFO Registered loader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3d4eac69 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:299)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,152] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,152] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,152] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,152] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,152] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,152] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,152] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,152] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,152] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.DoubleConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,153] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.FloatConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,153] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,153] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.IntegerConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,153] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.LongConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,153] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,153] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,153] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ShortConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,153] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,153] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,154] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Key' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,154] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Value' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,154] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Filter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,154] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HeaderFrom$Key' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,154] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,154] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Key' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,154] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.MaskField$Value' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,154] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampRouter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,154] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,155] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HoistField$Value' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,155] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,155] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.MaskField$Key' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,155] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.DropHeaders' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,155] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Cast$Key' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,155] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Cast$Value' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,155] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.PredicatedTransformation' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:230)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,155] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key' 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:476)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,159] INFO Added aliases 'VerifiableSinkConnector' and 'VerifiableSink' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:476)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,159] INFO Added aliases 'VerifiableSourceConnector' and 'VerifiableSource' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:476)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,159] INFO Added aliases 'ByteArrayConverter' and 'ByteArray' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:476)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,159] INFO Added aliases 'DoubleConverter' and 'Double' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.DoubleConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:476)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,159] INFO Added aliases 'FloatConverter' and 'Float' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.FloatConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:476)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,159] INFO Added aliases 'IntegerConverter' and 'Integer' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.IntegerConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:476)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,159] INFO Added aliases 'LongConverter' and 'Long' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.LongConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:476)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,159] INFO Added aliases 'ShortConverter' and 'Short' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ShortConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:476)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,159] INFO Added aliases 'JsonConverter' and 'Json' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:476)

    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    task.shutdown.graceful.timeout.ms = 5000
    topic.creation.enable = true
    topic.tracking.allow.reset = true
    topic.tracking.enable = true
    value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneConfig:376)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,182] INFO Creating Kafka admin client (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils:51)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,185] INFO AdminClientConfig values: 
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
    sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
    sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:376)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,236] WARN The configuration 'offset.flush.interval.ms' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:384)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,236] WARN The configuration 'key.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:384)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,236] WARN The configuration 'offset.storage.file.filename' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:384)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,236] WARN The configuration 'value.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:384)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,236] WARN The configuration 'plugin.path' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:384)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,236] WARN The configuration 'value.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:384)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,236] WARN The configuration 'key.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:384)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,236] INFO Kafka version: 3.2.3 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:119)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,236] INFO Kafka commitId: 50029d3ed8ba576f (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:120)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,236] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1663616090236 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:121)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,448] INFO Kafka cluster ID: DJo1pXxgRp6AbICWA4vciA (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils:67)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,448] INFO App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-1 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:83)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,454] INFO Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:659)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,454] INFO Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:663)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,454] INFO Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:669)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,461] INFO Logging initialized @1622ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log:170)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,492] INFO Added connector for http://:8083 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:117)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,492] INFO Initializing REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:188)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,496] INFO jetty-9.4.48.v20220622; built: 2022-06-21T20:42:25.880Z; git: 6b67c5719d1f4371b33655ff2d047d24e171e49a; jvm 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04 (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:375)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,510] INFO Started http_8083@581d969c{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8083} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector:333)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,510] INFO Started @1671ms (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:415)
```

Source I already try:
https://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html

Connector: (I use Elasticsearch 7.15)

```
name=elastic-source
connector.class=com.github.dariobalinzo.ElasticSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
es.host=127.0.0.1
es.port=1750
index.prefix=quickstart-events
topic.prefix=es_
```

topic: quickstart-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> give this error

There is no line of that output that says `ERROR`. In fact, all it says is that the Connect REST API server has started successfully...

```
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,492] INFO Added connector for http://:8083 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:117)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,492] INFO Initializing REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:188)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,496] INFO jetty-9.4.48.v20220622; built: 2022-06-21T20:42:25.880Z; git: 6b67c5719d1f4371b33655ff2d047d24e171e49a; jvm 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04 (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:375)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,510] INFO Started http_8083@581d969c{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8083} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector:333)
[2022-09-19 22:34:50,510] INFO Started @1671ms (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:415)
```

You have not provided your Elasticsearch properties file to the standalone server; you only provided `connect-file-source`, therefore nothing will be read from Elasticsearch.

Comment: So how to provided this? I modify the file connect-standalone.properties by what?

Comment: No. You run `connect-standalone.sh connect-standalone.properties elasticsearch-source.properties`, along with any other property files that you want to start connectors with. Or, you can use `connect-distributed.sh`, which is recommended way to run Connect and use its HTTP server to POST a JSON config definition instead of properties files. Also see - https://dariobalinzo.medium.com/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-source-connector-1a8c16a0e8eb

Comment: Hey I'm happy to report that I finally got it, it was a jar file dependency problem, and some configuration.
Thank you again for your help and the time you give to me.